# Grails 2.5.1 dbm-gorm-diff creates changesets to generate exiting indexes

Tags: grails, database-migration, grails-plugin, grails-2.0, liquibase

Whenever I run the `dbm-gorm-diff` command on a Mysql database, I get these annoying duplicates of named indexes (in my mapping closures), that do exist in the database, because when I try to execute the changesets, I get a duplicate index error.

I wonder what other people do? Should I just bite the bullet and remove these changesets manually every time I run a diff, or is there a smarter way out?

Comment: Unfortunately, we do this annoying stuff manually. I tried looking at this problem once, but I don't get much time to figure out the solution.